# Set OnClickEvent to widget

Tags: android, view, widget

I have a file called **otro_layout_relativo.xml** in the layouts folder, it contains:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".TimelineActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvOlrTitulo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ivOlrImgPerfil"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivOlrImgPerfil"
        android:text="Baño de burbujas"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivOlrImgBebe"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ivOlrImgPerfil"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/tvOlrTitulo"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/imagen_bebe" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivOlrImgPerfil"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
        android:src="@drawable/foto_perfil_papa" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvOlrFecha"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ivOlrImgPerfil"
        android:text="02/28\n1992"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textSize="10sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

In my **MainActivity** i have the folowing:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    botAniadir = (Button) findViewById(R.id.botAniadir);
    mainLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_linear_layout);

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {

            relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) View.inflate(this, R.layout.otro_layout_relativo, null);


            ((TextView) relativeLayout.findViewById(R.id.tvOlrTitulo)).setText("Elemento " + i);
            ((ImageView) relativeLayout.findViewById(R.id.ivOlrImgBebe)).setId(i);

            ivFoto = (ImageView) relativeLayout.findViewById(R.id.ivOlrImgBebe);
            ivFoto.setOnClickListener(new ListenerImagen());
            /*ivFoto.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Log.v("TAG", "onClick");

                    Log.v("ID", String.valueOf(v.getId()));

                }   
            });*/

            mainLinearLayout.addView(relativeLayout);

        }
```

What i want to do is to set an OnClickListener to the ivFoto widget (ImageView). I tried settings a class as a Listener and also a anonymous class but both gives me error and crashes the application.

In the **ListenerImage** i have:

```
public class ListenerImagen implements android.view.View.OnClickListener {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

        View padre = (View) v.getParent();

        if (padre != null) {

            Log.v("Listener", "Cliiiiik!");

        }

    }



}
```

Is there any form to do this?

Regards, Alex.

Comment: What does the logcat say?

Comment: @raghav-sood here you have the log: http://paste2.org/Fwkygy3e

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since View.onClickListener is an interface definition for a callback to be invoked when a view is clicked.You could simply do this:

```
ImageView your_image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.your_image);

your_image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {          
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                //do some
            }
        });
```

UPDATE: This is the cleanest and easiest way to do this, but also you could make your activity implement View.onClickListener and override the onClick() method.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It was easier than i tought.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. Multiple activities can't be displayed at the same time and you should *never* instanciate activities yourself.

Put the listener on your button inside the activities that contain it. And you would be better using inner classes (or anonymous inner classes) to listen to views. Doing it directly by setting the activity as a listener is not such a good practice as codes becomes bloated if you have many listeners.

Comment: Are you sure? I can change the values of the widgets from the another layout but if crashes when i try to set a OnClickEvent. I think i'm not dislaying multiple activities, im just inflating multiple layouts into my activity: relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) View.inflate(this, R.layout.otro_layout_relativo, null);